# Couldn't load shared library 'gdx-box2d.dll' for target: Windows 7, 32-bit

Tags: java, eclipse, dll, libgdx, box2d

I've checked other Questions and answers on here but still can't figure it out. I'm using eclipse with the android sdk installed and following the Learning Libgdx Game Development book.

The game worked fine on the desktop until I got to the chapter 11 about Box2D and now the game menu loads but when I go to play it crashes and I get

```
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load shared library 'gdx-box2d.dll' for target: Windows 7, 32-bit
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:117)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.<clinit>(World.java:187)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Unable to read file for extraction: gdx-box2d.dll
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.readFile(SharedLibraryLoader.java:126)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.loadFile(SharedLibraryLoader.java:261)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:115)
    ... 21 more
```

One answer I found online said "You'll also have to add the artifacts containing the native libraries, for the desktop" found this here [Couldn't load shared library box2d for libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23162438/couldnt-load-shared-library-box2d-for-libgdx).

In my core project I have referenced libraries that has the gdx-box2d-1.5.3.jar but in the desktop I don't have that. I tried importing it by using import and also tried adding it as a external jar but still nothing works. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated or a point in the right direction if this is already answered.

Update: I now actually have the gdx-box2d.jar in the desktop part of the project but still doesn't work and getting same error in the console.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Did you also reference gdx-box2d-natives.jar in your desktop project?
Anyway, here's how my project libs are. Look at the box2d ones (except box2dlights).

[image]

Also after setting references, I know it will sound stupid, but do a project clean up and restart Eclipse if you're using it. I lost count of how many times I've tried to fix an error that was not supposed to happen in the first place, and got fixed after restarting Eclipse.

Eclipse is love. Eclipse is life.

[image: Eclipse love]

Comment: Thank you very much Davlumbaz, Its working I would of never found how to fix it. You are a legend. Problem was I didn't have native jars for each platform.Your image of the libs you posted help me find it.